# dynamically update height of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page:- default.aspx.

I can change its height via css:-

```
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
    width: 919px;
    height: 850px;
}
```

just increase the height or decrease in the appropriate parameter.

But I am trying to implement a javascript functionality, where on the click of a button a certain function is initiated (onclienclick). Now with this function, added elements are added on the page, hence I want the page size to increase as well. and again the next click of the same button, the elements disappear, so I want the page height to decrease. I m thinking of a code similar to the following (but obviously my syntax is not correct). Can any one help?

```
$('main').css(‘height’) = 1186px; ????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery:

```
$('.main').height(1186);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2

Comment: Don't forget your selector needs to inclue a . before the class name.

Answer (score 5):

Easy peasy.

```
$('.main').css('height',1186);
```

It needs to be contained within the parenthesis. Also, jQuery assumes the number is px, so you don't need to explicitly call px. If you wanted to be fancy, you could use the native DOM names:

```
$('.main').css({height:1186});
```

No difference, just future reference in case you wanted to have multiple declarations you could do it all at once:

```
$('.main').css({
    height:1186,
    width:800,
    backgroundColor:'red',
    lineHeight:25,
    color:'blue',
    boxShadow:'0 0 10px rgb(0,0,0)'
});
```

You can do some crazy stuff!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the class name and the value goes inside the function. Also your quote marks are mixed. A full click function would look like this.

```
$("a.classname").click(function(){
    $(".main").css({ "height" : "1186px" });
});
```